# randomly rebooting server

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps

I have a VPS running Windows 2008 Web Edition 32bit.
Currently it is rebooting at random times every day, usually 2-3 times a day for no reason that I can see. 
The hosting company assures me that the host server is fine and not causing the reboots on my node, but there's nothing whatsoever in the event viewer that would suggest there is any problem. 
Before the server reboots, it generates a crash dump which I've run through the debugging tools - detailed below.

Any help or insight, very much appreciated.

---

BugCheck 101, {61, 0, 803cd120, 1}

Probably caused by : Unknown_Image ( ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE )

### Followup: MachineOwner

0: kd> !analyze -v

---

- *
- Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
- *

  ---

CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT (101)
An expected clock interrupt was not received on a secondary processor in an
MP system within the allocated interval. This indicates that the specified
processor is hung and not processing interrupts.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000061, Clock interrupt time out interval in nominal clock ticks.
Arg2: 00000000, 0.
Arg3: 803cd120, The PRCB address of the hung processor.
Arg4: 00000001, 0.

### Debugging Details:

BUGCHECK_STR:  CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_2_PROC

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  3

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  DRIVER_FAULT_SERVER_MINIDUMP

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  1c

STACK_TEXT:
8d107a60 81cc88e5 00000101 00000061 00000000 nt!KeBugCheckEx+0x1e
8d107a94 81cca67d 8d107d1b 000000d1 8d107b24 nt!KeUpdateRunTime+0xd5
8d107a94 81c61bae 8d107d1b 000000d1 8d107b24 nt!KeUpdateSystemTime+0xed
8d107b24 81c7894b 8d107b84 00000000 c3e6e000 nt!KeFlushMultipleRangeTb+0x11a
8d107c08 81c543f8 c3e6f000 0001c000 8d107d10 nt!MmSetAddressRangeModified+0x32b
8d107c98 81c554cb 84ea0344 00000000 00000001 nt!CcFlushCache+0x395
8d107cec 81c52645 84e94008 8d107d10 00000000 nt!CcWriteBehind+0x115
8d107d44 81cc2e22 84a6b978 00000000 84e6f840 nt!CcWorkerThread+0x11e
8d107d7c 81df2f7a 84a6b978 a77a75f2 00000000 nt!ExpWorkerThread+0xfd
8d107dc0 81c5befe 81cc2d25 80000000 00000000 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x9d
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 nt!KiThreadStartup+0x16

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: Unknown_Module

IMAGE_NAME:  Unknown_Image

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_2_PROC_ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE

BUCKET_ID:  CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_2_PROC_ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE

### Followup: MachineOwner

Comment: Check this hotfix.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955076/en-us

Comment: I had a look at this, but it seems the only hotfix I can download is for Vista?

Comment: Vista and 2008 are essentially the same thing.  The hot fix applies to both operating systems.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, my hosting company eventually conceded that this was an issue on the host server rather than on my node. As is often the case, I appear to be the only customer reporting the issue, even though it affects many others.

They'd fixed the issue their end, and I'm afraid I've not been told what it was.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an error caused by a driver.

If you are able to install drivers on your system, then you should revert your last driver installs.

If you are not allowed to install drivers, then you should change your hosting provider. Hopefully they do a better job in maintaining their servers.